# Google Chrome Inspecting Issue. Not showing CSS paths for local files

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, web-inspector, inspect

I am having very unexpected problem on my Google Chrome inspector today. When I was inspecting  my local HTML files I noticed I was unable to see from which css file, my classes were coming from. It's very strange because it's always showed it before. Here is the Screen shot

[image]

But if I inspect the web form not from Local it shows the files:

[image]

Why it's doing this? Is it doing it because of any recent Updates of Google Chrome ? How I can make it work for Local files too ? I need it badly.

Thanks

Comment: good question! :+1: I got the same issue...

Comment: They are probably cached to speed up loading time.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue by referencing source maps **relative to the workspace root**.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820529/chrome-not-showing-the-css-source-file-name-for-the-style/29311443#29311443) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems as you.
Try to uncheck "Enable CSS source maps" in the "Sources" group of "DevTools settings".
I suppose that one is for SASS/LESS files, but for some reason it affects normal CSS files as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. See https://crbug.com/422073 to track the progress on this issue and comment there if you have additional information. I am not able to reproduce this problem so far.